# How to write the User name in the Navigation Drawer of a navigational activity From One of its Fragments?

Tags: android

HomeActivity.java (Navigational Activity)

```
   import android.app.Fragment;
   import android.app.FragmentManager;
   mport android.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
   import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
   import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.DTO.User;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Fragments.BrowseAdFragment;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Fragments.LoginFragment;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Fragments.NetworkErrorFragment;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Fragments.TopMainFragment;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.R;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.utils.CheckNetworkConnection;
   import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.utils.NetworkErrorFragmentSetter;

   public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
   implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
   private Fragment fragment;
   private String title;
   private DrawerLayout drawer;
   private NavigationView navigationView;
   private View layout;
   private User user=null;
       @Override

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("REUZ");
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,                          R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.bringToFront();
    System.out.println(getSupportActionBar().getHeight());
    View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    layout=headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.navigationHeader);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("REUZ");

    this.setInitialFragment();
    this.listeners();

    /*this.getUserObject();*/
}
   public void listeners(){
   layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(CheckNetworkConnection.isConnectionAvailable(HomeActivity.this))
        {
            getLoginFragment();
        }
        else{
         fragment=                         NetworkErrorFragmentSetter.getNetworkErrorFragment(HomeActivity.this);
         replaceFragment();

     }
    }
});

       getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new                FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        Fragment currentFragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
        if (currentFragment instanceof TopMainFragment) {
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle("REUZ");
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof BrowseAdFragment) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Categories");
        }
        else if (currentFragment instanceof LoginFragment) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("LOGIN");
        }
        else if(currentFragment instanceof NetworkErrorFragment){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("NETWORK ERROR");
        }

               }
});
   }
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     //drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}
       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
       @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the home action
        setInitialFragment();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_browse) {
                fragment=new BrowseAdFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_submitAd) {
                Intent intent=new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),SubmitAdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_ads) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_wishList) {

    }
        replaceFragment();
     //drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void setTitleOnActionBar(String title) {


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}


public void setInitialFragment(){
    fragment=new TopMainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
   // ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
public void getLoginFragment(){
    fragment=new LoginFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
public void replaceFragment(){
    FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set the title

}
public void getUserObject(User user){
    this.user=user;

    if(user!=null){
        changeLayoutName();
    }
}
public void changeLayoutName(){
   TextView name= (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    name.setText(user.getName());
}
}
```

LoginFragment.java(Fragment)

```
         import android.app.Fragment;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.text.Editable;
        import android.text.TextWatcher;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Activities.HomeActivity;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Activities.RegisterActivity;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Activities.UnableToLoginActivity;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.DTO.User;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.R;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Validator.IValidation;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.Validator.Validation;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.dao.IUserDAO;
        import com.example.dellpc.reuz_app.dao.UserDAO;


        public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText emailET, passwordET;
    private Button loginBTN;
    private TextView utlTV, registerTV, invalidEmailTV, invalidPasswordTV;
    private View view;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private User user;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // keep the fragment and all its data across screen rotation
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("LOGIN");
        this.mapping();
        this.listeners(view);
        return view;
    }


    public void mapping(){
        emailET = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.emailET);
        passwordET = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
        loginBTN = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.loginBTN);
        utlTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.utlTV);
        invalidEmailTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.invalidEmailTV);
        invalidPasswordTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.invalidPasswordTV);
        registerTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.registerTV);
    }

    public void listeners(View view){
        loginBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailET.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordET.getText().toString();
                validateAndMoveToActivity(email, password);

            }
        });

        utlTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent utlIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), UnableToLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(utlIntent);
            }
        });

        registerTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        emailET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                invalidEmailTV.setText("");
                invalidPasswordTV.setText("");
            }
        });

        passwordET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                invalidEmailTV.setText("");
                invalidPasswordTV.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void validateAndMoveToActivity(String email, String password){
        IValidation iValidation = new Validation();
        if(!iValidation.isFilled(email) && iValidation.isFilled(password)){
            invalidEmailTV.setText("This field is required");
        }
        else if(iValidation.isFilled(email) && !iValidation.isFilled(password)) {
            invalidPasswordTV.setText("This field is required");
        }
        else if(!iValidation.isFilled(email) && !iValidation.isFilled(password)){
            invalidEmailTV.setText("This field is required");
            invalidPasswordTV.setText("This field is required");
        }
        else
        {
            IUserDAO iUserDAO = new UserDAO(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

          /*
                if(iUserDAO.isEmailPasswordExist(email, password))*/
            if(iUserDAO.isEmailExist(email)){
            user=iUserDAO.isEmailPasswordExist(email,password);
            if(user!=null)
            {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Successful Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                HomeActivity home=new HomeActivity();
                    home.getUserObject(user);
                   /* Intent homeACIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    homeACIntent.putExtra("user",user);
                    startActivity(homeACIntent);*/
                    // Remove this fragment.
                    getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                else {
                    invalidPasswordTV.setText("Invalid email or password");
                }
            }
            else {
                // After successful login where do you want to move your activity.
                invalidEmailTV.setText("Invalid phone number or email");
            }
        }
    }
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putSerializable("user",user);
}


}
```

HomeActivity contains Two Fragments- Login And Top
Initially it shows top fragment
Login Fragment has a option for registration 
After successful registration the user is navigated to login fragment
Now after Login the control must reach to the "Top" and the name of the user has to written in the Navigation Drawer
How to do it?

this is my Drawer .t want to write name of User instead of welcome to Reuz

[HomeActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozoBS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're saving the user details in your local database, and then trying to load the data after the user has successfully logged in. The issue that you're facing is that the `TextView` is not being updated. One possible solution that you can call the `changeLayoutName()` method from the `onViewCreated()` method of the `TopMainFragment` itself.